# How to create an assymetric two-column layout?

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to create a two column layout, where the second column is moved downward a bit.
Currently I create a two column layout and `translateY` the second column, which is odd and doesn't play nicely with flow of other elements.

Is there any way to do this in a more natural way?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 12.4em;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.box:nth-of-type(2n) {
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.box--more {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, ea.</p>
<main>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box box--more">...</div>
</main>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, corrupti?</p>
```

Comment: Css-grid would be a better option here.

Comment: Yeah, I can also do it with a `column-count: 2` and get rid of flex stuff, but the problem with translateY still remains

Comment: You don’t need to translateY if you set out the grid the way you want. Have you investigated CSS grid?

Comment: Awww now I see what you're saying! putting an empty grid on top right and then every item uses two grid cells, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

As @a-haworth and @paulie_d kindly mentioned, it can be solved quite easily with css-grids by filling the gap with a placeholder item:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, fit-content(1em));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0.1em;
}

main::before {
  content: "";
  grid-area: 1 / 2;
}

.box {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.box--more {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, ea.</p>
<main>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box box--more">...</div>
</main>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, corrupti?</p>
```